# Share file of a workflow with assignees - Alfresco

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm making a custom workflow, and I want to share the file that I create a workflow with the assignees, because otherwise, the users only access the file through "I've recently modified" and when the task is done, the file disappears.

How can I share the file when I create the workflow with assignees?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "share with assignees"? Do you want the assignees to gain rights to change the file? Do you want the assignees to receive a task with a link to the file?

Comment: I want that assignees have the file in the "share files " for example or "my files" @StefanDeLaet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a executionflowlistener on start of workflow that gets the nodes in your workflowpackage and then adds the "user home" noderef as a secondary parent.

Get workflow package nodes :

```
 ActivitiScriptNode packageItemsbpm = (ActivitiScriptNode) execution.getVariable(BPM_PACKAGE);
List<ChildAssociationRef> packageitemAssociations =  nodeService.getChildAssocs(packageItemsbpm.getNodeRef());
```

Then iterate these wf package nodes, and add them to the assignees home folders:

```
for(String assigneeName : assigneesList) {
    ResultSet rs = getServiceRegistry().getSearchService().query(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE, "PATH:\"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:"+ assigneeName  +"\"");
    if(rs.length() > 0){
          NodeRef assigneeHome = rs.getNodeRef(0);                                        
          nodeService.addChild(assigneeHome, nodeRef, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, nodeService.getPrimaryParent(nodeRef).getQName());
    }
 }
```

Comment: But this shared files is the shared files of the assignees that I attach in my workflow? I can't understand how can I get the noderefs of these.

Comment: The shared folder is shared between everyone. If you want to share with a limited number of users, you should do the above with the user home of the individual assignees. You can find the noderefs of these homefolders by using a path search , example PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:mjackson"

Comment: Only one thing, packageNode is the nodeRef of the file attached to the workflow?

Comment: yes, correct. you can find these like this: ActivitiScriptNode packageItemsbpm = (ActivitiScriptNode) execution.getVariable(BPM_PACKAGE);

    return nodeService.getChildAssocs(packageItemsbpm.getNodeRef());

Comment: The two first parameters of the function createAssociation are NodeRef. How can I create a nodeRef to the path of the homefolders?

I'm trying this: `NodeRef assigneesNodeRef = assignees.get(i).getNodeRef();
                    nodeService.createAssociation(assigneesNodeRef, nodeRef, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS);` but this not gives to me the path.

Comment: And of course, I obtain an error: `Found 1 integrity violations:
   The association source type is incorrect:
    Source Node: workspace://SpacesStore/b2f97e3b-f3c8-4c60-852a-0d14783943a0
    Association: Association[ class=ClassDef[name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder], name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains, target class={http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base, source role=null, target role=null]
    Required Source Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder
    Actual Source Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content`

Comment: Can you help me with a solution for this?

Comment: I ve updated the answer. try using the nodeService.addChild(...) method instead